# Jenkins display result for a stage only

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently I have a linter stage in jenkins that is set up to catch errors, but my ask was to pass the build regardless of the linter issues.
I tried the below code, but the issue is that it will always just display build succesful, how do I display just the result of the second step for linter? Ideally with the status and some details about the errors.
Thanks

```
  stages {
    stage('step 1') {
      steps {
        sh 'do something'
      }
    }
    stage('Lint') {
      steps {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
          script {
            sh 'npm i'
            sh 'npm run lint'
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('step 3') {
      steps {
        sh 'deploy'
      }
    }
  post {
    always {
      script {
        msg = "${currentBuild.result}";
        slackSend(color: status_color, channel: '#coe', message: msg)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the "catchError" function. try the "try-catch":

```
try {
    sh 'npm i'
    sh 'npm run lint'
} catch (Exception e) {
    println("Exception: ${e}")
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```